# How to calling R code from C++

Tags: rcpp, rinside

I try to include R-code in C++ (Qt creator). To get familiar with the packages Rcpp, RInside and the R-source code R-3.0.1 I try to run the following example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include<iostream>
#include<Rcpp.h>
#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance

R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";   // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");           // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

exit(0);
}
```

**First Question:**

The file string.h comes from the package Rcpp, but it always generates a lots (130!) errors like:

- 'internal does not name a type'
- 'StringProxy does not name a type   etc.

What is wrong with it?

**Second Question:**

In the .pro file I have to include all subfolder of the packages separatly like:

- INCLUDEPATH += "W:\hesm\Private\Private\Qt files\ConnectToR\Rcpp\include\Rcpp\module"

Is it possible to include a folder (package) with all its subfolders in one quote?

Thanks

Comment: So this is really more a question on how to use Qt Creator. For Rcpp, all you should do is include Rcpp.h, other files are included from it.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong.  The code you quote is **verbatim** from the `examples/standards/rinside_sample0.cpp` file of the RInside package.

It so happens that there is also a complete Qt example in `examples/qt/` directory (albeit building a Qt application rather than a command-line one). You are expected to do

```
  qmake && make
```

and the binary is built --- because *all* the required logic is in the `.pro` file.

Your question really is about how to use Qt Creator / Qt build tools, and has nothing to do with Rcpp or RInside per se.

Our supplied examples all work as documented and expected. Build them, look at what `make` executes and infer what you need for your use with Qt Creator (which is a fine tool, but not one supported by R out of the box).  If you want to use it, you need to adapt to it locally.